# What is the required homomorphism satisfying $f(c)=c$ for all $c\in R$ and $f(X)=aX+b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

My question is related to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094549/finding-a-unique-ring-homomorphism).

I know from the Proposition that

> Let $φ : R → R'$ be a ring homomorphism. Given elements $a_1, · · · ,
>  a_n ∈ R'$ , there is a unique homomorphism $Φ : R[x_1, · · · , x_n] →
>  R'$ , which agrees with φ on constant polynomials, and which sends
>   $x_i$ to $a_i$ f0r each $i$.

The desired homomorphism is given by $Φ(\sum_{i=0}^nc_ix^i) =\sum_{i=0}^n
φ(c_i)a^i$
for $c_i ∈ R$.

I need to know what is analogous homomorphism for  the problem in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094549/finding-a-unique-ring-homomorphism).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(c)=c$ for all $c$ then

for $c=0$ we get $a0+b=f(0) =0$ so $b=0$ and

for $c=1$ we get $a1 +0 = f(1) =1$ so $a=1$.

Thus $f(X) =X$.